# How to listen multiple serial ports with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, communication, modem, serial-communication

I am using *[Serial COM Simply in C#](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=320)* by Noah Coad, and I have available ports on my machine which is COM1, COM2, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, COM10, COM11, COM12, COM13, and I use COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, COM10, COM11, COM12 with the ZyXEL Omni 56K modem. I use these seven ports with seven modems.

There are clients for getting an answer with these modems. I use the mscomm.ocx to listen to COM ports. My application is running successfully, but sometimes one modem is processing 50-100 requests and answer then it stops working and my clients are getting a timeout because they do not get the answer from the server (using a COM-port modem). First it is getting "RING" and then getting "CONNECT 1200/V.22b 2400/NONE" then getting orginal package of my client and I process this package and produce an answer to the client.

I use seven EXE files for open and listen to COM ports because when I use
one EXE file I do not process same time. I know I must use a thread, but I don't know how.

How can I listen to seven COM ports at the same time and doing my work with no problems? Always I want to my application work correctly and reply to all clients at the same time. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Serial_Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;

        private Sistem sistemim = new Sistem();
        private ParcaKontorRaporu parcaKontorRaporu = new ParcaKontorRaporu();
        private ParcaKontorYukleme parcaKontorYukleme = new ParcaKontorYukleme();
        private FaturaOdeme faturaOdeme = new FaturaOdeme();
        private FaturaRaporu faturaRaporu = new FaturaRaporu();
        private FaturaSorgulama faturaSorgulama = new FaturaSorgulama();
        private NumaraSorgulama numaraSorgulama = new NumaraSorgulama();
        private TamKontorRaporu tamKontorRaporu = new TamKontorRaporu();
        private TamKontorYkleme tamKontorYukleme = new TamKontorYkleme();
        private BakiyeSorgulama bakiyeSorgulama = new BakiyeSorgulama();
        private HavaleBildirimi havale = new HavaleBildirimi();
        private KartKontorSifresi kartSifresi = new KartKontorSifresi();
        private KartKontorRaporu kartRapor = new KartKontorRaporu();
        private FiyatListesi fiyatListesi = new FiyatListesi();
        private AylikKontorRaporu aylikKontorRapor = new AylikKontorRaporu();
        private AylikFaturaRaporu aylikFaturaRapor = new AylikFaturaRaporu();
        private SifreDegirtirme sifreDegistir = new SifreDegirtirme();
        private BankaExtra BankExtra = new BankaExtra();
        private Duyurular duyuru = new Duyurular();
        private DuyurularExtra duyuruExtra = new DuyurularExtra();
        private BankaListesi Bankalar = new BankaListesi();
        private KontorFiyatSorgula KontorFiyat = new KontorFiyatSorgula();

        string bugun = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        private AxMSCommLib.AxMSComm com;
        private Button btn_disconnect;
        private Label label1;
        private Panel panel1;
        string GidenToPos = null;
        private int count = 0;
        private IContainer components;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private ListBox listBox1;
        private Label sayiLbl;
        private Label label2;
        Char chr = (char)13;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitComPort();
        }

        private void InitComPort()
        {
            // Set the com port to be 1
            com.CommPort = 6;

            // This port is already open, then close.
            if (com.PortOpen)
                com.PortOpen = false;

            // Trigger the OnComm event whenever data is received
            com.RThreshold = 1;

            // Set the port to 9600 baud, no parity bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit (all standard)
            com.Settings = "1200,n,8,1";

            // Force the DTR line high, used sometimes to hang up modems
            //com.DTREnable = true;

            com.RTSEnable = true;

            com.DTREnable = true;

            // No handshaking is used
            com.Handshaking = MSCommLib.HandshakeConstants.comNone;

            // Use this line instead for byte array input, best for most communications
            com.InputMode = MSCommLib.InputModeConstants.comInputModeText;

            // Read the entire waiting data when com.Input is used
            com.InputLen = 0;

            // Don't discard nulls, 0x00 is a useful byte
            com.NullDiscard = false;

            // Attach the event handler
            com.OnComm += new System.EventHandler(this.OnComm);

            com.PortOpen = true;

            com.Output = "AT&F S0=1" + chr;
            com.Output = "ATM0" + chr;
            com.Output = "ATS7=90 +++ATH0" + chr;
        }

        private void OnComm(object sender, EventArgs e)  //  MSCommLib OnComm Event Handler
        {
           Thread.Sleep(400);

            if (com.InBufferCount > 0)
            {
                string response = (string)com.Input;

                ProcessResponseText(response);
            }
            com.PortOpen = true;
        }

        private void ProcessResponseText(string input)
        {
            string IslemSaati = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            if (input.Trim().Equals("RING"))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(IslemSaati + " - ringing...");
            }
            else
                if (input.Trim().Equals("CONNECT 1200/V.22b 2400/NONE"))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(IslemSaati + " - connecting...");

                }
                else
                {
                    char[] c = input.Trim().ToCharArray();
                    if (c[0].ToString() == "\x02")
                    {
                        count++;
                        sayiLbl.Text = "number of process : " + Convert.ToString(count);

                        string gidecekStr = null;
                        gidecekStr = GeleniTemizle(input);
                        GidenToPos = null;

                        char[] k = gidecekStr.ToCharArray();

                        if (k[0].ToString() == "X")
                        {
                            for (int i = 1; i < k.Length; i++)
                            {
                                GidenToPos += k[i];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GidenToPos = paketFiltre(gidecekStr);
                        }

                        listBox1.Items.Add(IslemSaati + " - Coming Package : " + input);

                        com.Output = GidenToPos;

                        listBox1.Items.Add(IslemSaati + " - Going Package : " + GidenToPos);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sayiLbl.Text = "number of process : " + Convert.ToString(count);
                    }
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public string paketFiltre(string gelen)
        {
            char[] c = gelen.ToCharArray();
            string gidecekStr = null;
            int secim = 0;

            if (c[18].ToString() == "1")
            {
                secim = 1;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "2")
            {
                secim = 2;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "3")
            {
                secim = 3;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "4")
            {
                secim = 4;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "5")
            {
                secim = 5;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "6")
            {
                secim = 6;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "7")
            {
                secim = 7;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "8")
            {
                secim = 8;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "9")
            {
                secim = 9;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "A")
            {
                secim = 10;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "B")
            {
                secim = 11;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "C")
            {
                secim = 12;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "D")
            {
                secim = 13;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "E")
            {
                secim = 14;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "F")
            {
                secim = 15;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "G")
            {
                secim = 16;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "H")
            {
                secim = 17;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "I")
            {
                secim = 18;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "J")
            {
                secim = 19;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "K")
            {
                secim = 20;
            }
            if (c[18].ToString() == "L")
            {
                secim = 21;
            }

            switch (secim)
            {
                case 1:  // Bakiye Sorgulama
                    gidecekStr = bakiyeSorgulama.BakiyeSorgula(gelen);
                    break;

                case 2:  // Para Kontr Talimati Gnderme
                    gidecekStr = parcaKontorYukleme.ParcaKontorYukle(gelen);
                    break;

                case 3: // Para Kontr Raporu
                    gidecekStr = parcaKontorRaporu.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 4: // Tam Kontr Talimati Gnderme
                    gidecekStr = tamKontorYukleme.KontorYukle(gelen);
                    break;

                case 5: // Tam Kontr Raporu
                    gidecekStr = tamKontorRaporu.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 6: // Numara Sorgulama
                    gidecekStr = numaraSorgulama.Sorgula(gelen);
                    break;

                case 7: // Fatura Sorgulama
                    gidecekStr = faturaSorgulama.Sorgulama(gelen);
                    break;

                case 8: // Fatura deme
                    gidecekStr = faturaOdeme.FaturaOde(gelen);
                    break;

                case 9: // Fatura Raporu
                    gidecekStr = faturaRaporu.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 10: // HAVALE/EFT BILDIRIMI
                    gidecekStr = havale.HavaleEftBildirimi(gelen);
                    break;

                case 11: // KART KONTR SIFRESI ALMA
                    gidecekStr = kartSifresi.KartKontorSifresiAlma(gelen);
                    break;

                case 12: // KART KONTR RAPORU
                    gidecekStr = kartRapor.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 13: // FIYAT LISTESI
                    gidecekStr = fiyatListesi.Liste(gelen);
                    break;

                case 14: // GNLK/HAFTALIK/AYLIK KONTR RAPORU ALMA
                    gidecekStr = aylikKontorRapor.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 15: // GNLK/HAFTALIK/AYLIK FATURA RAPORU ALMA
                    gidecekStr = aylikFaturaRapor.Rapor(gelen);
                    break;

                case 16: // SIFRE DEGISTIRME
                    gidecekStr = sifreDegistir.SifreDegistir(gelen);
                    break;

                case 17: // BANKA LISTESI
                    gidecekStr = Bankalar.Liste(gelen);
                    break;

                case 18: // BANKA EXTRA
                    gidecekStr = BankExtra.Liste(gelen);
                    break;

                case 19: // DUYURULAR
                    gidecekStr = duyuru.Liste(gelen);
                    break;

                case 20: // DUYURULAR EXTRA
                    gidecekStr = duyuruExtra.Liste(gelen);
                    break;

                case 21: // KONTR FIYAT SORGULA
                    gidecekStr = KontorFiyat.Sorgula(gelen);
                    break;
            }
            return gidecekStr;
        }

        public string ConvertToHex(string asciiString)
        {
            string hex = "";
            foreach (char c in asciiString)
            {
                int tmp = c;
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
            }
            return hex;
        }

        private string HexAsciiConvert(string hex)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i <= hex.Length - 2; i += 2)
            {

                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hex.Substring(i, 2),

                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));

            }

            return sb.ToString();

        }
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.com = new AxMSCommLib.AxMSComm();
            this.btn_disconnect = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.sayiLbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.com)).BeginInit();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            //
            // label8
            //
            this.label8.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            this.label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 109);
            this.label8.Name = "label8";
            this.label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 24);
            this.label8.TabIndex = 22;
            this.label8.Text = "Gelen/Giden Paketler :";
            //
            // com
            //
            this.com.Enabled = true;
            this.com.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(491, 109);
            this.com.Name = "com";
            this.com.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("com.OcxState")));
            this.com.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 38);
            this.com.TabIndex = 14;
            //
            // btn_disconnect
            //
            this.btn_disconnect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(533, 72);
            this.btn_disconnect.Name = "btn_disconnect";
            this.btn_disconnect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 23);
            this.btn_disconnect.TabIndex = 17;
            this.btn_disconnect.Text = "Baglantiyi kes";
            this.btn_disconnect.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_disconnect_Click);
            //
            // label1
            //
            this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(251, 17);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 24);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 24;
            this.label1.Text = "DARKOCEAN";
            //
            // panel1
            //
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
            this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.sayiLbl);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn_disconnect);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 104);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 23;
            //
            // label2
            //
            this.label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(251, 41);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 24);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 26;
            this.label2.Text = " MODEM - 2";
            //
            // sayiLbl
            //
            this.sayiLbl.AutoSize = true;
            this.sayiLbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.sayiLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
            this.sayiLbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 72);
            this.sayiLbl.Name = "sayiLbl";
            this.sayiLbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
            this.sayiLbl.TabIndex = 25;
            //
            // listBox1
            //
            this.listBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 136);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 134);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 27;
            //
            // Form1
            //
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 270);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.com);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label8);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "DARKOCEAN";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.com)).EndInit();
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // If com port is open then close it
            // to disconnect connection

            if (com.PortOpen)
            {
                com.PortOpen = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnected...", this.Text,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        public string GeleniTemizle(string gelen)
        {
            string DATA = null;
            string LRC = null;

            string temp1 = gelen.Replace("\x02", "");
            string[] tempArray = temp1.Split('\x03');


            string kontrolLRC = "";

            string gelenLRC = tempArray[1];

            sbyte[] array;

            array = sistemim.PrepareLRCPacket(tempArray[0]);

            foreach (sbyte ch in array)
                LRC += Convert.ToChar(ch);

            kontrolLRC = LRC[LRC.Length - 1].ToString();

            if (gelenLRC == kontrolLRC )
            {
                DATA = tempArray[0];
            }
            else
            {
                sbyte[] array2;
                string LRC2 = null;

                array2 = sistemim.PrepareLRCPacket("000000000000215" + "package problem");
                DATA = null;

                foreach (sbyte ch2 in array2)
                    LRC2 += Convert.ToChar(ch2);

                DATA = "X" + LRC2;
            }

            return DATA;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **WOW! A lot of code there!** I would *highly* recommend that when you post questions you try to make them [sscce.org](http://www.sscce.org) compliant... you would get **much** better responses!

Comment: That's a lot of code, It could use some refactoring ;-)

Comment: Using a hopelessly outdated VB6 control, especially when you use threading, voids the warranty.  SerialPort class in .NET.

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken.

Comment: [Threading (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx) and [Using Threads and Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1dx6b2h.aspx) provide some background on .NET Threading.  A more recent capability is the Task Parallel Library's [Task Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your [COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) handling into a separate class. The class will have its own instance of the COM port and then you can create multiple instances of your wrapper class, one for each COM port you want to access.